# Integration and Laplace-Stieltjes of a multiplied Weibull and Exponential distribution Function

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, approximation, laplace-transform

I have a trouble for integrating a multiplied weibull and exponential distribution. The expression is as follows:
$$
Y(t) = \int_0^t e^{-\lambda T}e^{-(T/\mu)^z}dT\,.
$$
Then, I need to take Laplace-Stieltjes from Y as follows:
$$
W = \int_0^\infty se^{-st}Y(t)dt\,
=\int_0^\infty se^{-st} \int_0^t e^{-\lambda T}e^{-(T/\mu)^z}dT\ dt\
$$
I think you can read the expression and help with the question.

Actually, in above-mention problem z parameter have a special bounds as follows:

0 < z < 1

For example consider z = 0.5; Is there any solution or approximation for this problem at this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method of solving is shown below :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Why z parameter replaced by 2?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer : I was away. In fact, I made a confusion between "Z" and "2" in the script of the question because the size of the character was too small on the screen of my computer. A closed form exists with referenced special functions only in case of some particular values of "Z". In the general case, I think that a closed form cannot be found without defining a new and non-referenced special function.